# Why is my CAML query failing when it contains <Query>?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have a list with a lot of documents (> 5000). I need to retrieve one particular document from it. I use this query:

```
@"<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name=""FileLeafRef""/>
                <Value Type=""Text"">MyDocumentName</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>"
```

And I get a ServerException stating that this operation is forbidden because it goes over the list treshold.

But if I remove the `<Query>` tag:

```
@"<View>
    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>"
```

It works, and retrieve a single file, which sadly isn't the one I wanted, obviously.

So I'm puzzled here. Why is it behaving like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eventually finding the right keywords to ask Google, I found [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62609/spquery-works-on-libraries-under-the-list-view-threshold-but-not-over).

The problem is that no field in my library is indexed, therefore when I try to add a query with conditions, all the library has to be read through in order to find the document(s) I need. So obviously, if there is too many documents, I get the exception.

`<RowLimit>` doesn't prevent this behavior, it only acts on the **result** of the query.

That being said, **there is one field that is automatically indexed: ID**. So we can change our query a bit to manually page the documents whose ID are between two values, and simply put the query in a `while` loop, incrementing the current ID paging each time, like so:

```
ListItemCollection items = null;
const int paging = 2000;
int currentPaging = paging;

while (items == null || items.Count == 0 || currentPaging < 100000)
{
    var query = new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = $"<View><Query><Where><And><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>MyDocumentName</Value></Contains><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>{currentPaging}</Value></Leq><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>{currentPaging - paging}</Value></Gt></And></And></Where></Query></View>"
    };

    items = list.GetItems(query);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    currentPaging += paging;
}
```

Here's the formatted XML used in the query (`query.ViewXml`), for better readability:

```
    <View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                    <Value Type='File'>MyDocumentName</Value>
                </Contains>
                <And>
                    <Leq>
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                        <Value Type='Counter'>{currentPaging}</Value>
                    </Leq>
                    <Gt>
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                        <Value Type='Counter'>{currentPaging - paging}</Value>
                    </Gt>
                </And>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

> Value Type=File

```
@"<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name=""FileLeafRef""/>
                <Value Type=""File"">MyDocumentName</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>"
```

If you don't like building the query by hand then a couple of good tools are:
- U2U CAML Query Builder which gives you an UI for building the query.
- CAML.NET which is a library for safely building CAML queries

Comment: Same problem. Whenever my CAML query contains a `<Query>` tag, it gets completely ignored and I get my exception.

Comment: Upvoted though for pointing out my mistake on the value type, and pointing to U2U which is excellent!